# JSON.parse appends , to string and then complains invalid token at ',

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm parsing a webpage with nokogiri and then iterating through css  selectors until I find the  I'm looking for Then I run a regex to match the javascript portion only, and then try to parse it with JSON.parse but that returns error invalid token at ',{ ... If I run puts on the matched data it shows it without the prepended comma but the error occurs when I run JSON.parse JSON::ParserError: 822: unexpected token at ',{"skuAttr":"200007763:201336106;491:200004763#145cm","skuPropIds":"

```
file=File.open('product.html')
doc=Nokogiri::HTML.parse(file)
doc.css("script").each do |page|
if page.text=~/skuProducts/
    skudata = page.text[/var skuProducts=\[(.+?)\];/, 1]
    puts skudata
            parsed = JSON.load(skudata)
end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're consistently seeing that comma prefixed and the rest of the JSON string looks valid... then why not just remove that leading comma and then try the JSON parse?

Comment: You're regex is probably wrong then and that is not a "leading" comma at the start of the whole string but somewhere in between. Whats the URL for that HTML? I bet your capturing regex is not properly capturing the whole value of `skuProducts`

Comment: Try enabling multiline mode in your regex: `page.text[/var skuProducts=\[(.+?)\];/m, 1]` notice the `/m` at the end of the regex

Comment: Didn't help Still get the same error https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Lifelike-adult-real-silicone-sex-dolls-realistic-small-breast-vagina-pussy-TPE-love-robot-doll-with/32959852599.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.108.426b39c5zkxl9w&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_1_10065_10130_10068_10890_10547_319_10546_317_10548_10545_10696_453_10084_454_10083_10618_10307_537_536_10902_10059_10884_10887_321_322_10103,searchweb201603_59,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=7975d470-4733-4613-8bf1-431f3d761b39-16&algo_pvid=7975d470-4733-4613-8bf1-431f3d761b39&transAbTest=ae803_4